# preliminary reading recommendation before embarking on Connes non commutative geometry book?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, index-theory

I want to try to understand non commutative geometry by reading Connes's book
..and I am discovering it is a hard book to read :-) as I miss a lot of background specially in operator algebra and homology theory ( my field is nonlinear PDE so I know a bit of functional analysis already- at least the one used in my field).

So my question:  what reading could be recommended in order to prepare a non expert mathematician to read Connes's book?
For example, there are so many book on operator algebra or homology theory ...and my personal pick will be random, so I am seeking for expert recommendations:

Thanks in advance
JF

Comment: Do you know some differential geometry?

Comment: yes basic riemanian geometry @undergraduate level

Answer (score 9):

To understand everything in Connes' book you would need expertise in many different fields. My advice would be to *browse* it and see if anything attracts your interest. Then you can read up on the relevant background for that topic.

Comment: I had a similar experience with Connes's book when I was an undergrad. It bewildered me beyond anything I had read on math before, also because it was (and probably still is) way above my head. However, I did realize then I would need to pick only a few of the many directions surveyed there to dig deeper. It was a game changer for me, nonetheless - it was the book that made me want to work on the field I am now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is what I have been doing  but I was wondering if there was some more efficient way to proceed,if such way exist of course.